# Remove history button from Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-simple-history

I want to enable/disable history from django admin button based on the type of user.

[image]

My end goal here is to be able to understand how to show hide this button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Django does not provide an easy way to toggle History button like it is done for 'Add' button, for instance. The easiest way would be to overwrite a [change_form.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html) and remove the next lines from `block object-tools-items`:

```
<li>
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
        <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
</li>
```

Keep in mind that you have to specify `change_form` for every admin model. 
Example:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # path to the app_name/templates/admin/app_name/change_form.html
    change_form_template = 'admin/app_name/change_form.html'

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Test, TestAdmin)
```

Comment: Instead of overriding the whole template, you can override just the `{% block object-tools-items %}`, although it has the "absolute url" part also.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to override `change_form_object_tools.html` [template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form_object_tools.html), which needs to be placed in `templates/admin/` of your project.

```
    {% load i18n admin_urls %}
    {% block object-tools-items %}

    {% block comment %}
     <li>
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as   history_url %}
        <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">
 {% translate "History" %}</a>
    </li>
    {% endcomment %}

    {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% translate "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. I also encounter this concern, and based on the answer of @elsadek and the comment of @daigorocub, this is how I manage to show/hide the history button/link.

create the admin template to override the default admin template for the `change_form_object_tools.html`, the directory would be `app/templates/admin/`.

this is my `change_form_object_tools.html` looks like. it is different from the default `change_form_object_tools.html` of django because I am using django-jazzmin for admin template, but the process is just the same.

```
{% load i18n admin_urls jazzmin %}
{% get_jazzmin_ui_tweaks as jazzmin_ui %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}

    # Validate if the user is super user, if true, the history button is displayed, else, remove the history button.
{% if request.user.is_superuser %} 
    <a class="btn btn-block {{ jazzmin_ui.button_classes.secondary }} btn-sm" href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}">{% trans 'History' %}</a>
    {% endif%}
    {% if has_absolute_url %}
        <a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-block {{ jazzmin_ui.button_classes.secondary }} btn-sm">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

for reference, this is the default `change_form_object_tools.html` of django which can be found in `..\python3.11\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\`

`change_form_object_tools.html`

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
    <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% translate "History" %}</a>
</li>
{% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% translate "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and I wasn't satisfied with the original answers. So I did a bit of digging and found out this solution. You can override `render_change_form` and call the `super` while setting `change=False` like this:

```
def render_change_form(
    self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url="", obj=None
):
    return super().render_change_form(
        request, context, add, False, form_url, obj
    )
```